# jquery .html not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace some div text automatically using the .html command in Jquery but it's not working for me. This is the code I have so far:

```
    <div id="test">123</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var refreshId = setInterval(function()

    {

    $('#test').html("test");

    }, 1000);


});

</script>
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? I have ran tests to make sure Jquery is working and it is, and if I run alert('test'); then that works fine.

Thanks for any help

**Edit: I have ran the script in another file on localhost and it works fine - could it be something within the code I'm using already that's stopping it from working? This is baffling me!**

Comment: It works very well: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ZKTKn/

Comment: Are you sure the interval is called?

Comment: by the way, are you sure you want to use `setInterval`? Maybe `setTimeout`?

Comment: What tests did you run? Have you loaded another library?  Please post more code.

Comment: It won't fix your issue, but assuming you have not altered the jQuery short-cut variable, you could replace `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` with `$(function(){`. Note that this should not alter the behaviour of the script.

Comment: The script works fine inside another file...is there something that could potentially be blocking this from working?

Comment: May be security issues. I had a similar problem. Try giving permissions to your folder that has js files. Hope it helps.

Comment: Got there in the end, problem was to do with different .php files and I had to manually include the Jquery file again...not sure why alert and the other tests were working though. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have problems like this it's usually due to some javascript/jquery prior to this part which is incorrect.

If you can, try proofing or commenting out some other parts of your code to see if you can make it work.

Comment: I found the problem :) I'm trying to do it in a wordpress theme and the theme calls different .php files and I had to include Jquery in the seperate PHP file as well. Not sure why alert() was working though, and the Jquery tests I got from here http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html

Answer (score 0):

In your full page code, is it possible that you have one more control with the same id? If so, jQuery can select it instead of your div.